# How to get the orientation of the element in autodesk forge

Tags: autodesk-forge, forge

I have a cabinet and I want to get the orientation of the cabinet. I want to automatically locate the front of the cabinet.I don't know how to get the orientation

Answer (score 0):

This is a tricky problem.

`Front` is relative to something. If you have a cabinet, one can assume the `Front` is where the `handles` are. Now assuming the `handle` is a block (AutoCAD), or a family (Revit), or a part (Inventor), your code may search for such an instance.

From the above, search for this object, then calculate a vector from the center to it. That will be the base vector for a [raytrace](http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2017/03/threejs-raytracing-in-the-forge-viewer.html).